# how do I allocate a pointer to a class with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, class, pointers, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have:

```
class Human {
    string choice;
public:
    Human(string);
};

class Computer {
    string compChoice;
public:
    Computer(string);
};

class Refree : public Human, public Computer {
public:
    string FindWinner();
};

int main() {
    Human* H1 = new Human("name");
    Computer* C1 = new Computer("AI");
    Refree* R1 = new Refree();
}
```

This code fails to compile with:

```
 In function 'int main()':
error: use of deleted function 'Refree::Refree()'
note: 'Refree::Refree()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition  would be ill-formed:
error: no matching function for call to 'Human::Human()'
note: candidates are:
note: Human::Human(std::string)
note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Why does this fail, and how can I construct a pointer to `Refree`?

Answer (score 3):

Since `Human` and `Computer` have user-declared constructors that take an argument, their default constructors are implicitly deleted. In order to construct them, you need to give them an argument.

However, you are trying to construct `Refree` without any arguments - which implicitly tries to construct all of its bases without any arguments. That is impossible. Setting aside whether or not it makes sense for something to be both a `Human` and a `Computer`, at the very least you have to do something like:

```
Refree()
: Human("human name")
, Computer("computer name")
{ }
```

More likely, you want to provide a constructor that takes one or both names, e.g.:

```
Refree(const std::string& human, const std::string& computer)
: Human(human)
, Computer(computer)
{ }
```